# copying from one sheet to another

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy my data depending on the column value. If column R has invalid, then it should copy all information from sheet1 to sheet2.

I have below code running. Due to some reason it does not copy the last two rows of my sheet1. 
I have 551 rows in sheet1 , and I have the 551 row column R as invalid. 'It checks only till 548 rows and skips the last row without moving them.

Could someone help me to fix this issue

```
Sub Tab()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim nextrow As Long
    Dim a As Double

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' get the count of rows in column r
    a = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
    MsgBox (a)

    For Each cell In Sheets("sheet1").Range("R5:R" & a)
    ' if the cell in column R has invalid, then copy the entire row to another sheet
        If cell.Value = "Invalid" Then
            nextrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("sheet2").Range("R:R"))
            Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & nextrow + 1)
        End If
    Next

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of `a` in the `MsgBox` ?

Comment: Perhaps the content of those last cells isn't exactly equal to "Invalid"?

Comment: in `a = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "R").End(xlUp).Row` you need to specify the sheet for `Rows.count` too like `a = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(heets("sheet1").Rows.count, "R").End(xlUp).Row`. Same for `Rows(cell.Row).Copy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & nextrow + 1)
```

try

```
Sheets("sheet1").Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A" & nextrow + 1)
```

Your code can be written as

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim nextrow As Long, a as Long
    Dim srcSht As Worksheet, destSht As Worksheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set srcSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    Set destSht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet6")
    nextrow = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(destSht.Range("R:R"))

    With srcSht
        a = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
        MsgBox a
        For Each cell In .Range("R5:R" & a)
            ' if the cell in column R has invalid, then copy the entire row to another sheet
            If cell.Value = "Invalid" Then
                .Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=destSht.Range("A" & nextrow + 1)
                nextrow = nextrow + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Also instead of pasting data row by row you can also use `UNION`.

Comment: same for `Rows.count` in  `a = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "R").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: `Dim a As Double` should be `Long`. Floating point doesn't make any sense, there are no half rows. Also you changed the upper/lower case of `cell.Value = "invalid"` which could cause problems.

Comment: How can this only cause a problem with the last two rows though?

Comment: @SJR If you don't specify a sheet for a range or `Rows` then VBA assumes the `ActiveSheet` for that command. If the active sheet is not the sheet you thought to be then eg. you got the wrong last row which might be 2 less then the sheet you originally wanted. So it looks like it misses 2 rows.

Comment: @Peh - I get all that, but `a` is defined as relating to sheet1 and so is `cell` so I don't see why it either doesn't work at all or works for every line. No sheet is activated during the code.

Comment: @Peh - Thank you for the corrections, answer updated.

Comment: @SJR lets assume `sheet1` is NOT the active sheet when starting the macro. Then in the original code `a = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "R").End(xlUp).Row` she used `Sheets("sheet1")` to specify `Cells` but `Rows.count` in this line is still `ActiveSheet.Rows.count` because no sheet is specified. So we get the row count of the active sheet (which is not sheet1) therefore not the correct row count.

Comment: @Peh - don't think that's right. I think the only issue with using `Rows.Count` unqualified is if you have a chart sheet which is active. Otherwise doesn't make a difference - I just tested because I know I'm usually wrong when I say things like that...

Comment: @SJR outch my bad :( Of course `Rows.Count` should be the same value in every worksheet of the same workbook. I need more coffee. So you are right that doesn't affect anything here, but what I said about that `Rows.Count` is referring to `ActiveSheet` and not to `Sheet1` it still correct. So it would be a good practice referring the same sheet here too. But you are totally right that can't really affect anything in this case because all worksheets should have the same total amount of rows. Good input!

Comment: @Peh - agreed, it is good practice and I try to adhere to it having been picked up on it myself here a few times!

Answer (score 1):

I will not go into the part on the variables and methodology (everyone has their way of scripting). I will respond based on your base code above, hopefully it is clear for your understanding.

```
Sub Tab()
Dim cell As Range
Dim nextrow As Long
Dim a As Double

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

' get the count of rows in column r
a = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.count, "R").End(xlUp).Row
MsgBox (a)

'This is assuming that you will always populate starting from the first row Range("A1") in Sheet2
nextrow = 1

For Each cell In Sheets("sheet1").Range("R5:R" & a)
' if the cell in column R has invalid, then copy the entire row to another sheet
    If cell.Value = "Invalid" Then

'Use the EntireRow function to copy the whole row to the Sheet2.
'During the next iteration, it will +1 to nextrow, so the next record will be copied to Range("A2"), next Range("A3") and so forth.

        cell.EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a" & nextrow)
        nextrow = nextrow + 1
    End If
Next

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```